# how to convert one json to TestResult

Tags: java, testng

We need to convert Json to the TestResult format data. How can we achieve this?  We couldn't build the ITestResult through Testng run and so need to convert the Json to TestResult by ourselves.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Have you tried anything ? Can you shear your implementation here?

Comment: Are you asking for a JSON to POJO converter, like Jackson?

Comment: I am trying to build one TestResult object by myself. But didn't how to get it implemented.

Comment: can you show us some example and implementation of what you tried?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to create object of **junit.framework.TestResult**, then just import it in the class and create an object after that iterate over json object and set the values of TestResult object.